# ContextSwitchDeadlock occured error when processing 2400images and 100video files

Tags: c#, winforms

I encountered this error when processing 20GB of image and video files. When i checked, my computer uses 11GB of RAM. i think the problem is in this code. It uses a lot of resources. I'm thinking 2 things, (1)release resources after processing file but it says the file is still in use (2)processing file without loading the image/video but im not sure with it.

```
Image image;

foreach (FileInfo file in MyFileFolder)
{
 image=Image.FromFile(@file.FullName.ToString());

 //my codes
}
```

How can i fixed this? I tried Option Tools>Option>Debugging>General> unchecked "Enable Just My Code" but its still the same.

Comment: Just continue and ignore the message. (or do the job async)

Comment: i tried that and just continue looping at 1780th image. i checked the property of the image, nothing is strange, jpeg, 6MB size.

Comment: Have you tried the `image.Dispose()`?  But I'm not sure is that related to your case

Comment: You know that you can continue, so where is your Problem? This message is just there while debugging in Visual Studio, so just ignore it. Check your code without Visual Studio and you will see nothing will happen. Your app will "just" freeze while your process is running. (if you dont care for a frozen app, than everything is fine) The message is only saying something like "hey, your main thread is blocked for more than a minute. Is something wrong? Are your sure you want that?"

Answer (score -2):

I can only tell from WPF but think this might be the same in winforms: If you run a long running calculation on the UI-Thread, you will see this exception in debug mode.

Just move your code to run in a seperate thread and you should not see this exception anymore.